# Variadic function: expression contains unexpanded parameter pack 'args'

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-functions

I want to write a vey simple log function that accepts any number of arguments and outputs them to console. Example usage:

```
LOG("hello");
LOG("hello", 1, 0.6);
```

I started implementing it like this

```
template<typename... Args>
void LOG(Args... args) {
    va_list vargs;
    va_start(vargs, args);
    // for (auto arg: vargs) {}
}
```

But the compiler (clang++) gives me the error in the title

```
expression contains unexpanded parameter pack 'args'
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: The C variable arguments feature (using the ellipsis and `va_list` etc.) has nothing to do with variadic templates. Also: you cannot iterate over the arguments passed to either of them, since those arguments can have different types.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Usually logging functions are implemented using macros, so you can disable them altogether in release build for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this :

```
void LOG() {
    cout << endl;
}
template<class T, class... OtherArgs> void LOG(T&& var, OtherArgs&&... args) {
    cout << std::forward<T>(var);
    LOG(std::forward<OtherArgs>(args)...);
}
```

That is a recursive solution based on this [work](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2008_02/article2/) (explained [here](http://digitalmars.com/d/1.0/variadic-function-templates.html) as well)